# CSS object re-positioned with top blocking image map

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I've created an image map, and then put a youtube video with a

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-400;">
```

because I want it to display over the image. Then I have another Image I want to display below that, but it displays below where the video would have been, and if I use top:-400 to move the image up, it works, but some invisible field is blocking me from clicking parts of the image map.

Comment: Show your markup please.

Comment: `position:relative` keeps the space an element would have in normal flow reserved – if you don’t want that, use another method of moving the element up, for example a negative `margin-top`. And your issue of not being able to click is likely one of placement in the Z axis, so setting a `z-index` might help – but to be more specific on that, your problem description is too vague. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the How to Ask link, changing to the margin-top method did fix the problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use 'margin-top' instead of 'position:relative;top:-400px;'

This does keep the space of the original position.